# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: javascript, java, rest, jetty, dropwizard

I Am not able to fetch data from Rest Server.Following Error is coming:
"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access."

Response is coming as "0", This is not hitting the Rest Method also.

Rest APT:

```
@POST
    @Timed
    @Path("updateScore")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response updateScore(Player player)
    {
    StringBuilder returnStr = new StringBuilder("Sucess");
    return Response.ok().
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080").
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",  "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS").
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token").
            allow("OPTIONS").
            status(200).
            entity("Hello").build();
}

JavaScript Call

    var url = "http://192.168.0.101:9090/api/FGame/updateScore/";
            var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
            client.open('POST', url, true);
            client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            client.send('{"Name" : 12}');
            client.onreadystatechange = function() {
                   alert(client.status);
                   alert(client.data)
            };
```

But if I am changing to JavaScript call as following then working fine.
JavaScript Call

```
    var url = "http://192.168.0.101:9090/api/FGame/updateScore/";
            var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
            client.open('POST', url, true);
            client.send(null);
            client.onreadystatechange = function() {
                   alert(client.status);
                   alert(client.data)
            };
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775364/enabling-cors-in-dropwizard-not-working This should be what you are looking for. You are trying to use `CORS` headers but you need to configure the server (Jetty in this case) and it resources what `CORS` headers are allowed. Also your Javascript is connecting to port `9090` but you are receiving error about port `8080`. This shows that you may have 2 HTTP webservers and you are configuring one of them but expecting configuration change at the other.

Comment: Thanks @zloster, working for me

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario I am using an angular front-end Api to collect the data from a form object and a Java rest Api to write the data to a MySql database. But I was always having the *"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."* error in the browser console. None of the suggested header modifications in the frontend like;

```
const headers: {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
};
```

worked for me.

After hours of research in the internet one of my friends showed me the answer in not in the frontend but in the backend. Adding a WebConfig class to my java code fixed my problem.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

 @Override
 public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000/", "http://localhost:4200/")
            .allowedMethods("*")
            .allowedHeaders("*");
 }
}
```

Hope this finds those who is looking for an answer to the same error.